# Add rows obtained in loop from dataframe to new data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am comparing two dataframe and I want to print the match result in new dataframe if the match is found if the match is not not enter blank row in the same data frame. I have tried using  append command but  it is not working. any help would be appriciated.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,4,3,4,5],
                      'SMILES': ['a b c d','a b c d','a b c d','dd c b e','f d','e f'],
                    'c': [1,3,7,2,0,3]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,3,4,6,7,5],
                      'SMILES': ['a b','dd d ','f','z','k h','e'],
                     'c': [1,2,0,3,0,4]})
name1=df1['SMILES']
name2=df2['SMILES']
df4= pd.DataFrame(columns=df1.columns)
for  i in name2.index:
            match=(name1.str.contains(name2.iloc[i]))

            if match.any():
                #if the match is found then enter all the coulmns found in new dataframe
                data=df1[df1['SMILES'].str.contains(name2.iloc[i])]
                df4.append(data)

            else:
                #if the match is not found enter a blank row in the same dataframe
                df4.append(pd.Series())
print(df4)
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Try using `df4.append(pd.Series(),ignore_index=True)` in your else statement and check if its what you want, I do not understand what is your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign your new dataframe, i.e., use `df4 = df4.append(data)`. Also, as Jonas Palačionis pointed out, you have to use `ignore_index=True` for the empty row. Whole script:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 4, 3, 4, 5],
                    'SMILES': ['a b c d', 'a b c d', 'a b c d',
                               'dd c b e', 'f d', 'e f'],
                    'c': [1, 3, 7, 2, 0, 3]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 5],
                    'SMILES': ['a b', 'dd d ', 'f', 'z', 'k h', 'e'],
                    'c': [1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4]})
name1 = df1['SMILES']
name2 = df2['SMILES']
df4 = pd.DataFrame(columns=df1.columns)
for i in name2.index:
    match = (name1.str.contains(name2.iloc[i]))

    if match.any():
        # if the match is found then enter all the coulmns found in new dataframe
        data = df1[df1['SMILES'].str.contains(name2.iloc[i])]
        df4 = df4.append(data, ignore_index=True)

    else:
        # if the match is not found enter a blank row in the same dataframe
        df4 = df4.append(pd.Series(), ignore_index=True)
print(df4)
```

This results in the following output:

```
     a    SMILES    c
0    1   a b c d    1
1    2   a b c d    3
2    4   a b c d    7
3  NaN       NaN  NaN
4    4       f d    0
5    5       e f    3
6  NaN       NaN  NaN
7  NaN       NaN  NaN
8    3  dd c b e    2
9    5       e f    3
```